# Django 3rd party image uploading service from browser

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi
I want users to be able to upload their own photos from the browser, but I read that it isn't safe to let them upload files to your server without many protections. I need a image hosting website that has an easy API for uploading photos (for free).

The only one I have found is Cloudinary, which is awesome, but following their tutorial didn't work. I guess the reason is it's outdated, and I'm using Django 1.10...

If there is a way of doing so, even without a special API, (by sending requests to some image hosting site) I would like to give it a try as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a non-commercial application, you might want to check out [Imgur](http://api.imgur.com). Their API is free for open-source applications and non-commercial applications.

A note from their official API page: *Each application can allow approximately 1,250 uploads per day or approximately 12,500 requests per day.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This isn't really a Django solution because I can't seem to find a Django app for this API, but I guess I could just create one that sends the requests with python.

Comment: @real_2 I am not sure this still works but you might want to see this: https://github.com/leofiore/django-imgur

Comment: This looks pretty bad, it hasn't been updated for the last 2 years and has code that was copy pasted from something that has something to do with dropbox... (?) I think I can work with https://github.com/Damgaard/PyImgur ...